# ORA-01002 Fetch Out of Sequence with Temporary Table and .Net

Tags: oracle, .net-core, stored-procedures, temp-tables, oracle19c

I have a stored proc in Oracle that I am trying to call from a .Net Core app.

The proc loops through a cursor to populate a Global Temporary table, and attempts to send the result back as a ref cursor.

```
 Type ssp_rec_refcur Is Ref Cursor; -- Return ssp_rec;

 Procedure temp_table_sel(p_ssp_rec_refcur  Out ssp_rec_refcur) Is

    Cursor cur_main Is
      Select item1
            ,item2 etc..
        From regular_table;
  
  Begin
  
    For c_rec In cur_main Loop
          -execute some functions to get supplemtary data based on cursor row
           
          --store values in temp table for ref cursor
          Insert Into global_temp_table
          Values
            (c_rec.item1, c_rec.item2, c_rec.item3 etc...);

        End If;
      End If;
    End Loop;
    
    Open p_ssp_rec_refcur For
      Select * From global_temp_table;  
  
  Exception
    When Others Then
      log_error($$plsql_Unit, 'temp_table_sel');
  End temp_table_sel;
```

This works fine when testing on the DB itself, but when I try to execute it from .Net, I am getting the error: ora-01002 fetch out of sequence.

If I put a Commit; command right before the select statement it gets rid of the error, but the table is then empty as it deletes rows on commit;

If I put a Commit after the Select statement, it goes back the error.

How can I read the temporary table rows into a ref cursor without triggering a Fetch Out of Sequence error?

Comment: I think the problem is outside this procedure. Check the code that reads from the cursor, I assume you still try to read from the cursor after the last record has been fetched.

Comment: @MartinSchapendonk I think it was Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll sending an autocommit after the transaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here's what I think was happening.

The problem is that the temp table was defined with the attribute "ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS;", so when it ran on the DB side it was fine because there is no commit.

However when calling it from .Net, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll does an autocommit at the end of every transaction, which caused the temp table to delete it's rows, thus invalidating the cursor before I could read it.

My work around was set the temp table to "ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;" so that the autocommit didn't delete them and it now reads the cursor as exptected.

I put a change in the proc to get the user's session ID and store that in the temp table as well, then delete from the table by session ID if the user queries again in the same session to avoid any duplicate data since it will not delte automatically after the transaction.